# F# 4.5.0.0: Compilation errors: FS1198, FS0661 and FS0001: I'm adapting a interface from C# to F#

Tags: compiler-errors, functional-programming, f#, c#-to-f#

My goal is to port FSharp.Core version 4.5.0.0 to .NET 4.0. To achieve my goal I am rewriting parts of Theraot.Core in F#, since FSharp.Core does not "accept" third party libraries: https://github.com/theraot/Theraot/issues/121.

I'm adapting a interface from C# to F#.

Interface in C#:
https://github.com/theraot/Theraot/blob/master/Framework.Core/System/Collections/Generic/IReadOnlyDictionary.cs

Type in F#:

```
namespace System.Collections.Generic

open Microsoft.FSharp.Core

type IReadOnlyCollection<'T> =
    inherit IEnumerable<'T>

    abstract Count : int with get

type IReadOnlyDictionary<'TKey, 'TValue> =
    inherit IReadOnlyCollection<KeyValuePair<'TKey, 'TValue>>

    abstract Keys : IEnumerable<'TKey> with get
    abstract Values : IEnumerable<'TValue> with get
    abstract Item : key : 'TKey -> 'TValue with get
    abstract ContainsKey : key : 'TKey -> bool
    abstract TryGetValue : key : 'TKey * [<System.Runtime.InteropServices.Out>] value : byref<'Value> -> bool
```

Where compilation errors occur:
https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/map.fs#L626
https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/fslib-extra-pervasives.fs#L88

When in C# to F# works perfectly, but compilation errors from F# to F# occur:

map.fs:

FS1198  The generic member 'TryGetValue' has been used at a non-uniform instantiation prior to this program point. Consider reordering the members so this member occurs first. Alternatively, specify the full type of the member explicitly, including argument types, return type and any additional generic parameters and constraints.

FS0661  One or more of the explicit class or function type variables for this binding could not be generalized, because they were constrained to other types.

fslib-extra-pervasives.fs:

FS0001  This expression was expected to have type
    ''a'
but here has type
    ''T'

I also tried, without success:

```
abstract TryGetValue : key : 'TKey * [<System.Runtime.InteropServices.Out>] value : 'Value -> bool
```

Edit:
I'm taking my first steps in F#. The only information I found was that the immutability of F# is very cool, but sometimes it is not possible to write F# as like C#.

The first two compiler errors I do not know where it came from, but the third is possible to simplify:

```
namespace TestBugApplication1

open System.Collections.Generic

type DictImpl<'SafeKey,'Key,'T>(t : Dictionary<'SafeKey,'T>, makeSafeKey : 'Key->'SafeKey) =
    interface IReadOnlyDictionary<'Key, 'T> with
        member this.ContainsKey(key) = raise (System.NotImplementedException())
        member this.Count = raise (System.NotImplementedException())
        member this.GetEnumerator() = raise (System.NotImplementedException())
        member this.GetEnumerator() = raise (System.NotImplementedException())
        member this.Item
            with get (key) = raise (System.NotImplementedException())
        member this.Keys = raise (System.NotImplementedException())
        member this.TryGetValue(key, r) =
            match t.TryGetValue (makeSafeKey key) with
                            | false, _ -> false
                            | true, value ->
                                r <- value //<- Compiler error
                                true
        member this.Values = raise (System.NotImplementedException())
```

I can also send a download link with the solution I am programming.

Comment: It's really hard to answer this without a concrete reproducible example. Can you simplify your code so that you have something that exhibits the issue, but can be posted here as a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem isn't in the implementation, rather the definition of `IReadOnlyDictionary`.

```
abstract TryGetValue : key : 'TKey * [<Out>] value : byref<'Value> -> bool
```

Notice that it's `'Value`. Which implies that `TryGetValue` will have a signature of `TryGetValue<V>(TKey key, out V value)` instead of `TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)`.

Correcting it to

```
abstract TryGetValue : key : 'TKey * [<Out>] value : byref<'TValue> -> bool
```

will make it compile.

The additional errors are inference errors. If you're implementing overloaded members, annotate the types to avoid ambiguity.

```
member this.GetEnumerator() : IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<'Key, 'T>> = 
    raise (System.NotImplementedException())

member this.GetEnumerator() : IEnumerator = 
    raise (System.NotImplementedException())
```